# C++ class composition,why constructor not called?

Tags: c++

I have the following code and i don't understand, why at the creation of object b, the constructor of class A doesn't called.......I will appreciate a little help.hank you very much.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class MyClass
{
    int x;
public:
    MyClass(int y);                           
    MyClass(MyClass &my) 
    {
        x = my.x;
        cout << "My class created by copy" << endl;
    }
};
MyClass::MyClass(int y)
{
    x = y;
    cout << "My class created" << endl;
}

class A {
    MyClass k;
    public:
        A(MyClass &my) : k(my) {
            cout << "A created" << endl;
        }
};
class B {
    A data;
    public:
        B(A& aa) : data(aa)
        {
            cout << "B created" << endl;
        }
};
int main()
{
    MyClass obj(100);
    A a(obj);
    B b(a);                     
    return 0;
}
```

---

execution:

```
My class created
My class created by copy
A created
My Class created by copy
B created
```

Comment: `**` Bolding out stuff in code view doesn't work with markup. Please edit!

Comment: Why the downvotes guys? New user. Welcome to SE.

Comment: Why the downvote?? **I really hate** the aggressive downvoting of [tag:c++] related questions, without leaving any comment (at least here I've noticed so). Giving some extra tags seems to relax this behavior, that's likely applied to 1st time or low reputation OPs. Give them a chance people! Try being helpful!

Comment: A note to the OP: You should accept the answer or prove it wrong, that's the other part of the (IMHO) intended SO culture!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`A`'s copy constructor is called, not the constructor you have defined. Since you have neither defined it nor deleted it, the default constructor is called. The default constructor will call the copy constructor of each of the member variables; I believe it is in the order of declaration.